# Outputting text to file Tkinter

Tags: python, file, tkinter

when I ask it to output entry box to file it doesn't do anything and since I'm new to python I'm a bit stuck, I know this is a simple problem but I'm not too sure how to fix it. Please help.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
window= tk.Tk()

def SignUp ():
    text = username_entry.get()
    file= open(r"C:/Users/willi/OneDrive/Documents/Scripts/username_info.txt", "w") 
    file.write(text)
    file.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    password_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

def createNewWindow():
    window1 = tk.Toplevel(window)
    canvas= tk.Canvas(window1,width=1920,height=1080)
    canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=tk.NW, image= Main)
    canvas.pack()
    signup_button=tk.Button(window1,width=23, text="Register!", font="CCDutchCourage2", fg="white", height=1, relief="flat", bg="#183936", command=SignUp)
    signup_button.place(x=840, y=665)
    username_entry= tk.Entry(window1,width=14, bg="#183936", font=('Ariston Comic Demo Regular', 35), relief="flat")
    username_entry.place(x=776, y=447)
    password_entry= tk.Entry(window1,width=14, bg="#183936", font=('Ariston Comic Demo Regular', 35), relief="flat")
    password_entry.configure(show="*")
    password_entry.place(x=776, y=555)


Main= tk.PhotoImage(file= r"C:/Users/willi/Images/Asset 15.png")
canvas= tk.Canvas(window,width=1920,height=1080)
canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=tk.NW, image= Main)
canvas.pack()
signup_button=tk.Button(window,width=23, text="Sign Up!", font="CCDutchCourage2", fg="white", height=1, relief="flat", bg="#183936", command=createNewWindow)
signup_button.place(x=840, y=665)
username_entry= tk.Entry(window,width=14, bg="#183936", font=('Ariston Comic Demo Regular', 35), relief="flat")
username_entry.place(x=776, y=447)
password_entry= tk.Entry(window,width=14, bg="#183936", font=('Ariston Comic Demo Regular', 35), relief="flat")
password_entry.configure(show="*")
password_entry.place(x=776, y=555)
```

Comment: when you say it "doesn't do anything" can you be more specific? If your code is *exactly* as above, then it won't do *anything* because you are missing a call to `mainloop()`. You need `window.mainloop()` at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken. Your program does indeed store a value in the `username_info.txt` file.

The problem is, you got two variables named `username_entry`. One is global (defined at the end of the script) and one is local (defined in `createNewWindow()`). `SignUp()` accesses the globally defined one. This corresponds to the *first* `tk.Entry` element in the *first window*. If you leave this element empty and only type in the user name in the second window, nothing will be stored.

Also, you missed the line `tk.mainloop()` in your posted example. `:)`

Comment: If this response solved your problem, please also accept this as the correct answer.